# Deploy dependent apps in tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have 2 .war files (spring boot) deployed with-in the same tomcat web-apps.
Lets say 'A' and 'B'. App 'A' will be exposing few rest endpoints. App 'B' during initialization, have to consume the endpoint from 'A'. App  'B' init code is something like this.

```
@EventListener( ApplicationReadyEvent.class )
    private void init(){
      // invoke API from App 'A'
    }
```

Also, tomcat is configured in such a ways that it deploys A first and then B. But during B startup, the API call fails as the tomcat is not yet ready to serve requests. Feign API call times out and App B fails to start. After this, if i try to restart only App B, it will be successful as the API will now succeed.

Can someone let me know if there is a solution to resolve this dependency problem without having to restart the failed app ?

Thanks
Venkatesh

Comment: I don't think, tomcat provides a way to enforce the order of deployment of apps present in the webapps.

Comment: Is that always a case, that your these two web apps are deployed in same tomcat instance?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your App A and App B, can reside in separate tomcats, then deployment order is obviously into your hand.
but for specific scenario which you have mentioned here, for that below solution can work.

You can maintain some common file where you can write the status of App A once it is completely initialized and during it's initialization period , App B will keep on checking the status from the file.Once, the required status is found, then App B can start making calls to App A.